# How to combine ToC of two documents, Vol.I and Vol.II, to Vol.I?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing a book with two volumes, would like to have the TOC of both volumes in Vol.I.

Vol-One.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{Vol-Two}

\pagestyle{headings}\markright{Begriffs--Sammlung}

\begin{document}
\title{Begriffs-- und Problemsammlung\\
       zur Theoretischen Physik\\
       \vspace*{24pt}I. Begriffe}
\author{Ralph v. Baltz}
\maketitle

% how to show TOC of both Vol.I and II?
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Grundbegriffe]{Grundbegriffe}
\label{GBegr}
Wenn wir von der Physik als Wissenschaft sprechen, so meinen wir einen Wissens-- und Erfahrungsschatz der
\emph{reproduzierbaren Ph\"anomene} der Natur,
den der Mensch im Lauf der Geschichte angesammelt und mit gro\ss em Erfolg systematisiert hat.

\newpage
\section{Physik, Mathematik und mehr}
Theorie als mathematisches Modell der Naturvorg\"ange.

Einstein ber\"uhmte Gleichung (\ref{eq1}). 

\chapter{Mechanik}
Die Klassische Mechanik beschreibt ----

\section{Newton'sche Formulierung}

\end{document}
```

Vol-Two.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{Vol-One}

\pagestyle{headings}\markright{Begriffs--Sammlung}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}

\begin{document}

\title{Begriffs-- und Problemsammlung\\
       \vspace*{12pt}zur Theoretischen Physik\\
       \vspace*{24pt}II. Probleme}
\author{Ralph v. Baltz}

\maketitle
 
% here TOC of Volume II only.
\tableofcontents

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\chapter{Grundbegriffe}

\section{Zwillingsparadoxon}
Zwillingsparadoxon, spektakul\"ar.

Eine Gleichung
\begin{equation}
  E = m c^2
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\section{Wellengleichung}
Text ababababababa

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like:

```latex
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \InputIfFileExists{Vol-Two.toc}{% USE THE SAME BASENAME AS FOR \externaldocument!
   }{}%
\endgroup
```

after `\tableofcontents`. But because you are using KOMA-Script, I would recommend to automatically do this from within the document preamble using `\AfterStartingTOC`. You could also add a prefix to the page number to make clear, that it is from volume II:

```latex
% Following environment is to fake file Vol-Two.toc of external document
% Vol-Two.tex. Don't use this for a real document!
\begin{filecontents}{Vol-Two.toc}
\babel@toc {german}{}\relax 
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {A}Grundbegriffe}{5}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {A.1}Zwillingsparadoxon}{5}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {A.2}Wellengleichung}{5}{}%
\providecommand \tocbasic@end@toc@file {}\tocbasic@end@toc@file 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{Vol-Two}

\pagestyle{headings}\markright{Begriffs--Sammlung}

\newcommand\voliiprefixnumber[1]{II-#1}%
\newcommand\voliiprefixnumberbf[1]{\textbf{II-#1}}%
\makeatletter
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{%
  \minisec{Volume-II}% print an additional small heading to group the ToC
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[pagenumberformat=\voliiprefixnumberbf,pagenumberwidth=2.5em]{tocline}{part,chapter}%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntries[pagenumberformat=\voliiprefixnumber,pagenumberwidth=2.5em]{tocline}{section,subsection,subsubsection}%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
   \InputIfFileExists{Vol-Two.toc}{% USE THE SAME BASENAME AS FOR \externaldocument!
     \typeout{ToC of external document read}%
   }{%
     \typeout{Cannot find ToC of external document}%
   }%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Begriffs-- und Problemsammlung\\
       zur Theoretischen Physik\\
       \vspace*{24pt}I. Begriffe}
\author{Ralph v. Baltz}
\maketitle

% how to show TOC of both Vol.I and II?
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Grundbegriffe]{Grundbegriffe}
\label{GBegr}
Wenn wir von der Physik als Wissenschaft sprechen, so meinen wir einen Wissens-- und Erfahrungsschatz der
\emph{reproduzierbaren Ph\"anomene} der Natur,
den der Mensch im Lauf der Geschichte angesammelt und mit gro\ss em Erfolg systematisiert hat.

\newpage
\section{Physik, Mathematik und mehr}
Theorie als mathematisches Modell der Naturvorg\"ange.

Einstein ber\"uhmte Gleichung (\ref{eq1}). 

\chapter{Mechanik}
Die Klassische Mechanik beschreibt ----

\section{Newton'sche Formulierung}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table of Contents of Vol.1 and 2]

See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\DeclareTOCStyleEntries`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. However Latex processing of the supplied file (Vol-One) didn't work. Errors: Line refers to \tableofcontents: 
! Undefined control sequence.\tb@toc@after@hook ...-II}\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[pagenumberformat=\voliipr... \tableofcontents

! Undefined control sequence.\tb@toc@after@hook ...ter}\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[pagenumberformat=\voliipr... \tableofcontents. Tried to replace \minisec{Volume-II}% by Vol-Two, but no success. Perhaps I didn't fully understand your answer,

Comment: @Ralphvonbaltz With exactly my code? I've tested with current KOMA-Script version 3.41 and TeX Live 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 and 2023 and it works without error with all these versions. Option `pagenumberwidth` needs at least KOMA-Script v3.27. So it would not work with the original KOMA-Script version of TeX Live 2018 or older. So if your TeX distribution is older, you should update (at least KOMA-Script). But if my example works, but your own modification does not, please ask a new question with minimal working example.

Comment: @Ralphvonbaltz BTW: The `\minisec` command is only to group the ToC. It is something like `\subsubsection*`. If you don't need it, you can remove it or replace it by another sectioning command. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information about `\minisec`.

Comment: Thanks for help. Almost perfect, yet TOC of Vol. I should also have a heading, like Vol. II. I will look for local support to fix the problem with latex.